# How do I create an Outlook rule that moves all email from a specific domain to a folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I want to create a rule that moves all non-corporate email to a separate folder.

I don't mix work and personal business, but I would like to separate renewals and subscriptions from MSDN and TechNET from email I receive from my colleagues.

I want all email NOT sent from a specific domain, like `@example.com`, to go to a separate folder.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a new message rule

Step 1: Uncheck all boxes

Click Next. Outlook will ask 'This rule will be applied to every message you receive. Is this correct?' Choose Yes.

Step 2: 'Move to *specified* folder'

Specify a folder and click Next.

Step 3: 'Except with *specific words* in the senders address'

Specify @mydomain.com

Comment: Thanks, close enough... this article explains it http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook/HA010347751033.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link @Chris, that's the answer that worked for me!

Comment: @Chris Link is broken

Comment: There is no "next," and the above url is dead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create an address book that holds all of your personal email contacts and create a rule that moves the message using the condition `sender is in specified Address Book` where the address book is the one you just created.

Of course, the real question is why you have personal email sent to your corporate email address. Any email sent through your work system is subject to their rules and regulations regarding email. They generally reserve the right to read any email that comes in and do whatever they want with it, since it's using corporate resources for personal use. Retention policies also apply meaning if they require all messages to be deleted after 30 days of receipt or retained indefinitely for legal reasons it'll apply to your personal mail as well. It would probably be smarter to have your personal email elsewhere and check it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could filter it the other way by selecting "With specified words in the sender's address" and add in the sender's domain, (i.e., 'business.co.uk') and move to the specified folder.

If you do it that way, you can have one rule that handles several variations, such as subs.business.co.uk, news.business.co.uk, survey.business.co.uk. etc., all in one rule.

Comment: More than 12 years after, how is this better than accepted answer?

Comment: Because the accepted answer is not possible using current version.